# Escape sequences with "echo -e" in different shells

Tags: shell, escape-characters, echo

I just noticed that it seems like the flag `-e` does not exist for the `echo` command in my shell on Linux.
Is this just a messed up setting or is it "normal"?

Some code as an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e "\e[3;12r\e[3H"
```

Prints:

```
-e \e[3;12r\e[3H
```

This worked before! I guess some `stty` commands went terribly wrong and now it does not work anymore. Somebody suggested that my `sh` was actually just `bash`.

Comment: There's no such thing as a _"Linux shell"_. There's for instance _the `echo` builtin of the `/bin/sh` shell as provided by the `dash` package on Debian_ (an operating system that can have Linux or FreeBSD as its kernel).

Comment: And this is why I just put escape characters in my script when I need them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because you used `sh`, not `bash`, then `echo` command in `sh` doesn't have option `-e`. From `sh` manpage:

```
echo [-n] args...
            Print the arguments on the standard output, separated by spaces.
            Unless the -n option is present, a newline is output following the
            arguments.
```

And it doesn't have `\e`, too:

```
        If any of the following sequences of characters is encountered
        during output, the sequence is not output.  Instead, the specified
        action is performed:

        \b      A backspace character is output.

        \c      Subsequent output is suppressed.  This is normally used at
                the end of the last argument to suppress the trailing new‐
                line that echo would otherwise output.

        \f      Output a form feed.

        \n      Output a newline character.

        \r      Output a carriage return.

        \t      Output a (horizontal) tab character.

        \v      Output a vertical tab.

        \0digits
                Output the character whose value is given by zero to three
                octal digits.  If there are zero digits, a nul character
                is output.

        \\      Output a backslash.

        All other backslash sequences elicit undefined behaviour.
```

Comment: Several `sh` implementations support `echo -e`, at compilation time `bash` can be told not to support `echo -e`. It's just that _that particular sh_ (probably `dash`) doesn't support `-e` while _that particular `bash`_ does.

Answer (score 23):

`-e` is not POSIX (in fact, POSIX echo generally accepts no options, though it is allowed to support `-n`, see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/echo.html)), and `/bin/sh` on your system appears to be a POSIX shell. `-e` is an extension accepted in some shells, but you shouldn't rely on it, it's not portable. Ideally, use `printf`, or switch to using a shell which has `echo -e`.

Also see the caveats of `\e` in the comments below, which should be replaced with `\033`.

```
printf '\033[3;12r\033[3H'
```

Comment: as gnouc points out, `sh` doesn't recognize `\e` either. Use `\033`

Comment: Also beware that `printf` treats `%` as a substitution character whereas `echo` does not.

Answer (score 4):

Note that at any time and in almost any shell, you can figure out which "echo" will be called by typing `type echo` or `which echo`. It's usually a shell builtin. So it depends on which "echo" is installed and on which shell you're using.

Comment: `which echo` should not be used, it likely won't tell you if you are using a builtin because `which` is usually an external binary. `type` is good, though.

Comment: Well spotted, though on my main shell (zsh), it's a builtin (as revealed by `type which` or `which which`). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `zsh` wants to encourage us to use `printf "blah\n"` instead of `echo -e "blah\n"` for some reason.