# Why do some programs pass along TTY colours of child programs correctly and others not?

Tags: shell, tty

You can colour ttys by doing things like this

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "This is \033[0;31mRED\033[0m"
```

Often if another "parent" program runs `myscript.sh` as a sub-process then the colour codes will get correctly passed back and the shell running the parent will show the colours of the child.

Often it doesn't work. GNU Make is a counter-example

Makefile:

```
foo:
    ./myscript.sh
```

If I run `make foo` then the output is

```
This is \033[0;31mRED\033[0m
```

For some reason, `make` feels the need to escape the output of child processes.

I find this surprising since whoever wrote `make` would have had to add code, which is extra effort, to create an anti-feature. Or is it the case that applications such as `make` throw a switch on the tty which makes everything get escaped automagically? If so can I override this behaviour and force programs such as `make` to pass through child process data to the tty without transforming it? Or does each program control this behaviour its own way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script called by `make` needs to use the filesystem `echo`, not the builtin one

```
/bin/echo -e "\033...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your script relies upon a non-POSIX **`bash`** feature, but **`make`** is using **`/bin/sh`** for the shell, which (for instance, Debian) may be a different program such as **`dash`** (a more POSIX-compliant shell).

Further reading:

- [Escape sequences with “echo -e” in different shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells)
- [How do I print '-e' with echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168095/how-do-i-print-e-with-echo/168137#168137)
- [Which shell is used in GNU Make files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217243/which-shell-is-used-in-gnu-make-files)

Comment: Having extra features does not make a shell non-compliant. Additionally, the POSIX spec explicitly allows backslashes to be interpreted.

Comment: I just ran `echo -e "This is \033[0;31mRED\033[0m"` in sh, the colours came out fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas mentions in his answer, the shell being used by `make` is different than the shell you are using when you run the script manually.

As a general rule, if you're using features specific to a certain shell within a script, you should put that specific shell in the shebang line.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "This is \033[0;31mRED\033[0m"
```

Comment: My script already did that. Updated the question.